# Google map in Flutter not responding to touch events

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

I got two different screens inside Flutter app that use Google Map (provided by this [library](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter)).

Widget structure for first one is

> Scaffold -> ListView -> Visibility -> Center -> SizedBox -> GoogleMap

and for second screen it is

> Scaffold -> Container -> Column -> SizedBox -> GoogleMap

On both screens I got same map settings but for some reason on the first screen map is not responding to any touch events.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to tell the `GoogleMap` widget which gestures you want it to respond to by setting the `gestureRecognizers` property, something like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

...

GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(0, 0),
  ),
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
    ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
);
```

This is not specific to the `GoogleMap` widget, you would need to do this with any widget that uses `AndroidView`/`UIKitView` under the covers to handle gestures when it's placed inside a scrollable view.

Comment: thank you, what gestureRecognizers should be added besides PanGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I think you can add anything that implements [OneSequenceGestureRecognizer](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/OneSequenceGestureRecognizer-class.html) so `ScaleGestureRecognizer` and maybe `TapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: I added PanGestureRecognizer, ScaleGestureRecognizer and TapGestureRecognizer. When I start to scroll vertically over map - map is still not responding so that al listview is scrolled. but if i start to scroll map horizontally - it works, and I can move finger in vertical direction too. so the problem is that I can't start to scroll vertically now

Comment: @moonvader did you find a solution to that? I come across the same issue. It used to work when I added VerticalDragGestureRecognizer but now it is not. Edit: Found the solution. I just added the gesture recognizers from the answer below.

Comment: Does not work with `VerticalDrag` which is the main issue, even if you specify `VerticalDragGestureDetector` in the `gestureDetectors` set of `GoogleMap` object. Other answer contains the solution.

Answer (score 134):

I was with the same problem and I found the following solution after a long time of searching, just so it will work:

```
GoogleMap(
   gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>[
      new Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => new EagerGestureRecognizer(),),
   ].toSet(),)
```

The reason is that the `EagerGestureRecognizer` is a gesture recognizer that eagerly claims victory in all gesture arenas.

Reference:

[Manage gestures priority between two widgets](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28139)

[propriedade gestureRecognizers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AndroidView/gestureRecognizers.html)

Comment: I think this one works more efficiently than the rest for some reason. It is quicker on the gestures.

Comment: This worked for me. This solves the problem of putting gmaps inside the tabbar.

Comment: This allows for panning out too, which is perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: I need to add map widget in a modal bottom sheet and this one works for me.

Comment: Amazing!  Thanks so much!  I'm also noticing better responsiveness of the map with this - an added bonus.

Comment: Perfect! Working properly! Thank you!

Comment: I want to detect drag on the map. I add vertical and horizontal gesture recognizers as mentioned in the post. But how do I detect the actual gesture?

Answer (score 20):

I think it depends of what kind of gestures your parent widget support.

This way works for me. My map is in `TabBarView > ListView > GoogleMap`

```
 GoogleMap(
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
```

Answer (score 5):

I have similar problem, but in my case the map is inside sliver list (SliverPersistentHeader actually). Adding pan gesture worked, but i still cannot scroll the map vertically. So I also added `VerticalDragGestureRecognizer` and it worked as expected.

```
GoogleMap(
    gestureRecognizers: Set()
      ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
      ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
          () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
    // rest code
),
```

Note: You can also add another gestureRecognizer such as: `ScaleGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap with **Gesture Detector** and add *onVerticalStart*

```
GestureDetector(
    onVerticalDragStart: (start) {},
    child: GoogleMap(
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
            () => new EagerGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(
            Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
        ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
            () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),

      onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController c) {
        _controller.complete(c);
      },
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: LatLng(9.856326, 78.285448),
        zoom: 10.4746,
      ),
      mapType: MapType.normal,
      
    ),
  ),
```

[image: Flutter google map screenshot]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAYDB.png)}

Comment: gesture Detector is not working on googleMaps

Comment: Hi, I want to add layer on google maps with this text 'use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map', how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the widget structure for the first screen, I think the problem is that the `ListView` which is used is kept scrollable.
Due to this all the touch events are propagated to the `ListView` instead of the map.

Can you try adding the `physics` parameter to `ListView`?
You can try adding

```
ListView(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  /*Rest of the ListView implementation*/
)
```

**Update: A working example**

```
 return Scaffold(
    body: ListView(
      itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*1.2,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            buildMap(), /*The map function*/
            Container(
               /*Any other child widget*/
            )
          ],
        ),
        /*Any other child widgets in the List*/
      ],
    )
  );
```

Note: You need to start scrolling in horizontal direction for the map scrolling to work, since it will default to the ListView in case of vertical scroll.

Comment: Here's a way which seems to be working for me, which might work for you:
Wrap your child of `ListView` i.e. Visibilty` layer inside a `Column` and  set 'mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max` for the column.
Remove the `physics` property for the `ListView` and add some finite double value for `itemExtent: ` for the `ListView`.

I'll update my answer with an example code which is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind that `google_maps_flutter` is a developer preview, at version 0.2.  Please be patient for more features to be added.

Comment: So what is your point - wait till it will be in release? It can take months

Comment: It's google's work, and they can't comment on futures.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest solution for this issue.

I also found an alternative and refactored code where I think is more readable and cleaner that I found from this source (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PlatformViewSurface/gestureRecognizers.html) and is also working at the same time.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

GoogleMap(
...
gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
        Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
          () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
        ),
      },
...
)
```

As mentioned in the source,

> EagerGestureRecognizer is a special gesture recognizer that
> immediately claims the gesture after a pointer down event.

So the main key player to this, is the EagerGestureRecognizer.