# Implementing GoogleMap inside SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make fixed ScrollView with google map inside of FlexibleSpaceBar.

There's NestedScrollView with SliverAppBar and body content. Inside SliverAppBar is google map widget, app bar occupy the whole view of the device. There's also FloatingActionButton, which on press should scroll to the bottom of the view revealing body content of NestedScrollView and shifting map to app bar and vice versa. It technically works, there's a code if someone wants to see how it looks like:

```
@override
State<MapPage> createState() => MapPageState();
}

const LatLng _coordinates = LatLng(37.43296265331129, -122.08832357078792);

class MapPageState extends State<MapPage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
ScrollController _scrollController;
Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
double _scrollExtent;
bool _buttonState;

static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
  target: _coordinates,
  zoom: 14.4746,
);

@override
void initState() {
  _buttonState = true;
  _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0.0);
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _scrollController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  _scrollExtent = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      foregroundColor: Colors.red,
      onPressed: (){
        if(_buttonState){
          _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollExtent, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
          _buttonState = false;
        }
        else{
          _scrollController.animateTo(-_scrollExtent, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn);
          _buttonState = true;
        }
      },
    ),
    body: NestedScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              floating: false,
              pinned: true,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: Text("Title",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16.0,
                    )),
                background: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                  markers: _createMarker(),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Text(
            'Content'),
        ),
      ),
  );
}
Set<Marker> _createMarker() {
  return <Marker>[
    Marker(
      markerId: MarkerId("marker_1"),
      position: _coordinates,
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Marker"'),
    ),
  ].toSet();
}

}
```

The important part is here:

```
NestedScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            floating: false,
            pinned: true,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("Title",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                  )),
              background: GoogleMap(
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
                markers: _createMarker(),
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
```

There are 3 problems:

> 1. I dont understand how to prevent user from scrolling with gestures.

I want it to be controlled only by a scroll controller. I've tried to set physics of NestedScrollView to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), but it doesn't have any effect.

> 2. The map gesture detection inside scrollable widget behaving weirdly

You can't properly drag it and it seems to be only working with taps. In ListView, for example, it behaved fine with NeverScrollable physics.

> 3. Every time it's getting rebuilt in app bar it seems to cause some sort of memory leak and I'm getting next warning.

```
E/flutter (10644): #0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:39:31)
E/flutter (10644): #1      MapPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_app/map_page2.dart:83:35)
E/flutter (10644): #2      _GoogleMapState.onPlatformViewCreated (package:google_maps_flutter/src/google_map.dart:259:14)
E/flutter (10644): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10644): #3      AndroidViewController._create (package:flutter/src/services/platform_views.dart:599:15)  
...
```

If anyone can help out with any of those or maybe know examples of such implementation I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7):

I crossed the same problem, and found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57088480/6501536).

```
                background: GoogleMap(
                  gestureRecognizers: [
                    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                      () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                    ),
                  ].toSet(),
```