# How to use gestures on FlutterMap (flutter_map package) inside Column (or any scrollable View)?

Tags: flutter, dart, leaflet, gesture, fluttermap

I have the problem that I have a map inside a scrollable column. As map I use FlutterMap (flutter_map package). This is leaflet for flutter. In Google Maps there is a solution for exactly the problem by using "gestureRecognizers". The solution of the same problem with the Google Map packet: [Google map in Flutter not responding to touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280541/google-map-in-flutter-not-responding-to-touch-events) .

But how does this work with flutter_map? Or maybe there is a general solution for all kinds of widgets which need their own scroll gestures within a scrollable list or tabs?

I have that problem on more than one place inside my code. One special place is for example:

```
Scaffold -> Form -> TabBarView -> ListView -> Column -> Container -> FlutterMap
```

So the page is scrollable down (ListView) and to the right (TabBarView). So the Map is nearly not useable (feels like static but shouldn't be static). It's a long form which is splitted over several tabs and at one place the user should choose a location.

Many thanks and kind regards,
Jakob

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Malouda I'm sorry, but not so far. In most places I have adapted my UI so that the map is not integrated into scrollviews. But in some places this cannot be avoided and here I still have that problem. There is an open pullrequest, but it doesn't get the required approve...
https://github.com/fleaflet/flutter_map/pull/717

Comment: I also have a problem with including maps in scrollviews, tried them all. Fluttermap is the only one that is seamlessly fast in a scrollviews for me, but having trouble with implementing tilt-gestures on it (in full screen too, why I am here). But regarding layout, I may use a static image on the scrollview, and then let that map open in another screen for the user to view or do edits there rather. Similar to the Strava app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now with "flutter_map 0.14.0" it's finally fixed and works out of the box.