# FlutterMap and Scroll

Tags: flutter

I put a `FlutterMap` in a `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` with scroll direction of vertical

I want to keep map  interactive, currently if you drag in map horizontally everything is ok , but if you drag vertically, you change the scroll position, not the map bounds

How can I fix it?

Comment: How do you expect it to understand whether if you want to scroll vertically (the `Column`) or the map? 

Comment: I wrapped map in Padding, So there is some whitespace for scrolling, Also map height is small enough and you can easily scroll vertically by dragging top and bottom of map, I always want to scroll if drag from outside of map, and change map bounds if start drag from inside of map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid scrolling listview when scrolling in map within listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197268/how-to-avoid-scrolling-listview-when-scrolling-in-map-within-listview)

Comment: I'm not sure, I am using Flutter map not google map

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use gestures on FlutterMap (flutter\_map package) inside Column (or any scrollable View)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60858095/how-to-use-gestures-on-fluttermap-flutter-map-package-inside-column-or-any-sc)