# Google maps inside a form in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter

I have a `google map` inside `column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`. I can pan the map horizontally, but when panning vertically the `SingleChildScrollView` captures the event and scrolls itself. How can i pan the map when it receives any events, and scroll throught the `SingleChildScrollView` when the event is in other elemen

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
            child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  someInputs...,
                  _buildGoogleMap(),
                  someOtherInpus...,
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

Widget _buildGoogleMap(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 300,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0, top: 25.0),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        initialCameraPosition:
            CameraPosition(target: currentUserPosition, zoom: 14),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _googleMapController.complete(controller);
        },
        markers: [
          Marker(
            markerId: MarkerId('1'),
            position: LatLng(
                currentUserPosition.latitude, currentUserPosition.longitude),
            infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'Drag and hold this to location!'),
            icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarkerWithHue(
              BitmapDescriptor.hueRed,
            ),
            draggable: true,
            onDragEnd: (LatLng latLng) {
              this._dokanLatLng = latLng;
            },
          ),
        ].toSet(),
      ),
    );
```

so this is the code i am using to build a form that has some Textfields and a map with draggable marker so that the user can input location. The scrollview is working fine, but when i pan the google map up and down to navigate to a location, the event is not being handled by the map, the scrollview is scrolling even when i try to navigate the map. I want the map to handle its events by itself, so that the list doesnt scroll up and down when i try to pan the map vertically.

https://imgur.com/gallery/WUgfaX0

Comment: You can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280541/google-map-in-flutter-not-responding-to-touch-events) its similar question. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So the solution was to add to the google map widget, and it worked.

```dart
gestureRecognizers: {                 
  Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => EagerGestureRecognizer())
},
```

This replaces the default gesture recogniser with the 'eager' version which takes overall priority. As detailed in Flutter's docs:

> A gesture recognizer that eagerly claims victory in all gesture arenas.
>
> This is typically passed in AndroidView.gestureRecognizers in order to
> immediately dispatch all touch events inside the view bounds to the
> embedded Android view. See AndroidView.gestureRecognizers for more
> details.

Comment: ```gestureRecognizers: {
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
                  () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
                )
              },```

Comment: This code gives me this error "The method 'Factory' isn't defined for the type '_MapState'.".  How do I fix it?  I am new to Flutter and Dart.

Comment: In more recent Dart versions that's: `gestureRecognizers: const { Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(EagerGestureRecognizer.new), }`

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet, but not sure because question is not clear.

```
GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: _center,
          zoom: 0.0
      ),
      scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add( Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer())),
      polygons: polygon,
      markers: marker,
    );
```

Comment: No this is not  helping, can you check the description, i have added gif, hope it explains my query better

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedScrollView` for better behavior and make the height fixed for the `googlemap` ... I think this will do the work

Comment: The google map container has fixed height. And can you elaborate on how can i use NestedScrollView? Thank you

Comment: You can't use it in this case. This is not what `NestedScrollView` is for.