# Prevent Google map from scrolling inside SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, google-maps, scroll

I have a google map inside a "SingleChildScrollView" along with several other widgets.

The map does take large part of the screen height.

When I scroll the content and come to the map area and try to scroll, the whole page does not scroll. It scroll the map.

Is there a way to resolve this?

I still want to scroll the map also.
Maybe enable 2 finger scrolling on the google map?

```
GoogleMap(
              mapType: MapType.normal,
              initialCameraPosition: _cameraStartPos,
              onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                _mapController = controller;
                controller.setMapStyle(_mapStyle);
              },
              onCameraMove: (CameraPosition pos) {
                _zoomLevel = pos.zoom;
                _zoomLevelChanged();
              },
              onTap: null,
              myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
              zoomControlsEnabled: true,
              zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              mapToolbarEnabled: true,
              gestureRecognizers: Set()
                ..add(
                    Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => PanGestureRecognizer()))
                ..add(Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(
                    () => ScaleGestureRecognizer()))
                ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                    () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
              markers: Set.of(_markers.values),
            )
```

Comment: little late, this help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744359/google-maps-inside-a-form-in-singlechildscrollview

Answer (score 1):

Try to Wrap GoogleMap with IgnorePointer:

```
IgnorePointer(ignored: true, child: GoogleMap
```

or

Wrap GoogleMap and Transparent Container (same size as GoogleMap and on top of it) with Stack:

```
Stack(
  children:[
    GoogleMap,
    Container(color: Colors.transparant
  ],
)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It does work. But now I can't interact with the map. I do want to zoom and scroll the map. Is there a way to scroll it with 2 fingers?

Comment: no, you can't change the gesture behavior of google map

Answer (score 0):

You have to scroll outer the googleMaps widget boundaries to take the scroll effect or u can remove gestureRecognizers property and it will work just fine