# Google_maps pinch to zoom and double tap detection is possible in Flutter ..?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, pinchzoom

I am working on a google map.Actually, I want this functionality
when the user zooms the map or double-taps it on a map
position it will behave like an uber application. in uber map became static
when the user zoom or double-tap but I can't find this functionality
in the flutter map

> I'm using this package google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1

```
  Completer<GoogleMapController> completer;
GoogleMap(
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
          mapToolbarEnabled: false,
          zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
          zoomControlsEnabled: false,
          rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
          scrollGesturesEnabled: true,
          tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
          markers: locationData.locationMarkers.values.toSet(),
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(widget.lat, widget.long),
            zoom: 16.4746,
          ),
          onCameraMove: (position) {
            latitude = position.target.latitude;
            longitude = position.target.longitude;
          },
          onCameraIdle: () async {
            if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
              print("not workng");
              geoCodeProvider.setLatitude(latitude);
              geoCodeProvider.setLongitude(longitude);
            }
          },
          
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {

            widget.completer.complete(controller);

          },

      )
```

Comment: It should work. By default `zoomGesturesEnabled` are enabled. Could you share your code?

Comment: have a look ..my question has been updated..

Comment: zoom and double click is working. but what I need is..  when user zoom or double click on a particular postion ..the map will not move like became static.. like in the uber ride application. I'm facing the problem right now is when I'm double click on a position map ran away some time right or sometimes left..

Comment: Can you please provide more info? My Google Maps app works exactly like the Uber app!

Comment: you mean when you zoom the map with two finger  . map will bacame static..  I mean map will not moving when you zoom

Comment: please tell me what kind of info you need.. what you are mean to "more info.".?

Comment: if your map work exact same as uber. then please share your code

Comment: Have you checked this answer? Maybe it could be related to your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366611/7046992

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to add gestures in google map

```
GoogleMap(
  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(0, 0),
  ),
  gestureRecognizers: Set()
    ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()))
);
```

Handling zoom level when user interact with the map

```
 GoogleMap(
      zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
      tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
      onCameraMove:(CameraPosition cameraPosition){
         print(cameraPosition.zoom);
      },
    )
```

Add this for minimum or maximum zoom level in the map

```
minMaxZoomPreference: MinMaxZoomPreference(13,17)
```

Comment: but how can I handle when user zoom with two finger . and map will stop moving

Comment: You can use `onCameraMove()` method

Comment: Okay we stop oncamera move I make the logic .. but how we detect that user is zooming the map .or user double tap on map..? When we found these detection. Then it possible to stop onmove camera method