# GoogleMap card in Column in SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, google-maps, scroll, singlechildscrollview

I am using the **GoogleMap Widget** from the google_maps_flutter package. I have placed the **GoogleMap widget** in SizedBox with width and height of 300 in a **Column** with other children. I have placed the **Column** in a **SingleChildScrollView** because there are many children. When the Column doesn't use the **SingleChildScrollView**, there is no problem. But when there are enough children so that scrolling is necessary, the GoogleMap widget becomes impossible to zoom in or pan (move the viewport) with gestures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google map in Flutter not responding to touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54280541/google-map-in-flutter-not-responding-to-touch-events)

> Solution snippet:
>
> ```
> gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
>           Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(
>             () => EagerGestureRecognizer(),
>           ),
>         },
> ```